# Run a pipeline cleanup automatically after a merge request was merged

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

We are in the process of adding dynamic deploys to a testing environment where each merge request gets its own url, to be able to manually do frontend testing for people who are not developers.

These instances are deployed with `docker-compose` and GitLab CI/CD which works well.

I now want to automatically shut down these instances, once the merge request is merged.

So far, I have this extra step to manually shut down the testing instance:

```
deploy-dynamic-down:
  tags:
    - docker
  stage: deploy-dynamic
  script:
   - docker-compose down
  when: manual
```

This works well, but requires a manual step which will almost certainly be forgotten every now and then, requiring us to clean our runner every now and then.

**So, my question is:** can I trigger this pipeline step to run only when a merge request is merged?

I can't just limit this pipeline to certain branches like `master` or `develop`, because we don't always create merge requests to only these branches. I don't know which branch the merge request will target beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Gitlab Environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) to achieve this.

You can configure a [dynamic gitlab environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment) to be created for each one of your testing environments.

You can set your **deploy-dynamic-down** step to be executed when the [testing environment is stopped](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment).

**The key part here is that the environment will be automatically stopped when the source branch is deleted.**

Workflow:

1. Create a feature branch
2. Deploy a testing environment
3. Create a merge request (Check the **Delete source branch when merge request is accepted.** checkbox) You can also check **Delete source branch** when merging a Merge Request.
4. When the merge request is accepted, the feature branch will be deleted, and the corresponding gitlab environment will be stopped. This will trigger the **deploy-dynamic-down** step.

Comment: @kolaente can you share your code on how you accomplished dynamic deployment  where each merge request gets its own url? I am trying to do the same thing, but unsure whether I should use AWS ECS...